# Drag to fill duplicates values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, spreadsheet, drag-and-drop

I want to create a sequence of dates that populate a column.

| A |
| --- |
| 2023-12-31 |
| 2023-12-30 |
| 2023-12-29 |
| ... |

`Format Cell` is set to `Date`.
`Calculation Options` is set to `Automatic`
`Enable fill handle and cell drag-and-drop` is enabled.

I have tried using a reference cell with the current date and then a formula, `=$A$1-1; =$A$1-2; =$A$1-3; ...`, as this has worked for other types of values that had the same issue, to no avail.

If I manually enter the correct value in the first cell and then drag to fill, it duplicates this value in every cell.

```
2023-12-31
2023-12-31
2023-12-31
...
```

If I manually enter the correct values in the first two cells and then drag to fill, it duplicates both of these values in the same sequence.

```
2023-12-31
2023-12-30
2023-12-31
2023-12-30
2023-12-31
2023-12-30
...
```

So on and so forth.

**Microsoft Office Home and Student 2021**

Comment: `N` stands for number, which is a common placeholder for numbers. I've edited the question nonetheless.

Comment: Instead of `=$A$1-1; =$A$1-2; =$A$1-3; ...,` in the cell `A2` you could put the formula `=A1-1`  when you drag it down the column it will become `{ A2-1; A3-1, A4-1; ...}`

Comment: @BlindSpots that seems to work. strange. how come the other way does not work?

Comment: I rewrote it as [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1773312/) with an explanation for why it works. Ty for editing your question ;-)  Keep contributing.

Answer (score 1):

In `A2` use the formula `=A1-1` and then drag it down the column.

```
         A   
   +------------+
 1 | 2023-12-31 |
   +------------+
 2 | =A1-1      |
   +------------+
```

which will create

```
         A   
   +------------+
 1 | 2023-12-31 |
   +------------+
 2 | =A1-1      |
   +------------+
 3 | =A2-1      |
   +------------+
 4 | =A3-1      |
   +------------+
 5 | =A4-1      |
   +------------+
 6 | =A5-1      |
   +------------+
 7 | =A6-1      |
   +------------+
 8 | =A7-1      |
   +------------+
       etc.
```

The reason this works is that `A1` is a *relative* cell reference, a reference without the `$` sign in the row and column coordinates.   When you copy a formula that contains a relative cell reference, that reference will change relative to the position of the original cell and the new cell.  An absolute cell reference will not.

| Address | Relative Formula | Absolute Formula | Mixed (v1) Formula | Mixed (v2) Formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Copy `B10` to `C20` | `=B5` becomes `=C15` | `=$B$5` remains `=$B$5` | `=B$5` becomes `=C$5` | `=$B5` becomes `=$B15` |

**More Info:**   [Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)

Comment: a part of me expected the number that is being subtracted from `$A$1` to increase (e.g. `=$A$1-1`, `=$A$1-2`, `=$A$1-3`, ...) as the formula is dragged. how come this doesnt happen? is the drag autocompletion incapable of interpreting/manipulating explicit values?